# how to export or append multiple dataframes with different columns into a single excel sheet using R

Tags: r

I tried `XLconnect` and `Xlsx` but in vain.

the code is as below.

```
require(XLConnect)
require(xlsx)

a<-read.xlsx("C:\\R\\CPC2.xlsx",1,as.data.frame=TRUE)

b<-read.xlsx("C:\\R\\CPCVoucher1.xlsx",1,as.data.frame=TRUE)

wk <- loadWorkbook("XLConnectExample1.xlsx", create = TRUE)
writeWorksheet(wk, a, sheet = "test", startRow = 1, startCol = 2)

writeWorksheet(wk,b, sheet = "test", startRow = 15, startCol = 2)

saveWorkbook(wk)
```

Comment: You haven't said _how_ it didn't work.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question. Have a read through here to learn how to write questions that get useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1036500